# Check if a webelement is "clickable" before you click it - Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Forgive what is potentially an obscure question.
In the webtable displayed below the following code will click on the highlighted radio button and fire the JS associated with its "click" event.

```
Set myEle = ch.FindElementById("__M5_1_1_image")
myEle.Click
```

[image]

For reasons I will not bore you with, I am trying to write a function which will check if you can click on this (or another candidate webelement in the table) WITHOUT actually clicking on it as I do not want to fire the associated "click" event at this stage of the code. However, I do want to know that the webelement I have specified will not throw an error or produce no event when I do click it later.
I have tried  `.ClickAndHold`  and `.ReleaseMouse` as tests to see if the same potential errors are returned as with the use of `.click`, but this does not work. For example I can get a "Element not interactable error" with `.click` but no error with the other 2.

Going back to the webpage I notice that this (and all the other tables I want to apply this function to) change the mouse cursor from an arrow to a "pointing hand" graphic when you hover the mouse over the correct element (e.g. radio button image in this example). Hence, one method would be to look for the presence of the "mouseover" event in the list of event listeners for the specific webelement - as highlighted right lower pane of the image. Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to check the "event listeners" associated with a defined webelement using selenium and VBA. For example if I fire the mouseover event for a webelement would it return an error if no such event existed or would there merely be no action? I assume it is the later, so can anyone tell me if it is possible to query whether a specific event is associated on the webpage for a defined webelement?

Comment: Use a webdriverwait with an expected condition of elementToBeClickable: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By)

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins, however I don't think elementToBeClickable is present in Selenium VBA.